# Querying content from Android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating an Android Widget containg some contact info

I discovered that the getContentResolver()-method only exists in the Activity-class, and not in the AppWidgetProvider-class.

How do I query content from a widget?

Like so:

Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(SOME QUERY);

UPDATE:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        String people = getContacts(context);
        // Do something with people...
    }

    private String getContacts(Context context)
    {
        String peopleStr = "";
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
                String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
                String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + ("1") + "'";
        Cursor people = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
        while(people.moveToNext())
        {
            int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
            peopleStr += people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex) + "\n";
        }
        people.close();
        return peopleStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getContentResolver() is actually defined in [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver%28%29) class. That means, it is possible to call that thru the context passed in appwidgetprovider.onupdate() and those related methods.

Comment: The program/widget crashes after i try to insert it on the homescreen. I have added an example to the original post.

Comment: Never mind. I had forgotten to add the READ_CONTACTS-permission in AndroidManifest.xml